# Best way to structure async Express GET request

Tags: node.js, express, async-await

I have been looking to update my Express skills by incorporating async/await handling and had a quick question.

From the examples I have seen online, most requests are structured wrapped inside of a try/catch block and add any await tasks to a variable before handling them.

```
app.post('/signup', async(req, res) => {
  const { email, firstName } = req.body
  const user = new User({ email, firstName })
  const ret = await user.save()
  res.json(ret)
})
```

My code looks like this:

```
app.route("/articles")
  // GET: articles
  .get(async (req, res) => {
    await Article.find((err, results) => {
      if (!err) {
        res.json(results);
      } else {
        res.send(err);
      };
    });
  })
```

Should I assign the response from my Mongoose to find to a variable as the first code block example and handle in a try/catch, or does my code essentially do the same thing and in a way that's the best practice as is?

Thanks in advance!

Cheers,
James

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Be aware that there are two very different uses of the word `async` in javascript. The first is the general concept of asynchronous functions which can be implemented in any language and is widely used in javascript with various design patterns (callback, promises, `async/await`). The second is the `async` keyword which is used to allow the usage of `await` and only works on promises (does not work in callbacks).

You seem to be confusing the two. Because of this I now advise people not to use the word "async" when referring to asynchronous functions and only use it to refer to the `async` keyword.

Your function does not return a promise because you passed a callback to it. As such it **cannot** be used with `await`. Because you cannot use `await` it makes no sense to mark the function as `async`. I consider your code *buggy* even though it works - the mechanism still function (the `await` keyword conveniently ignores non-Promise functions like yours and does not generate an error) however it doesn't communicate your intent well and will confuse future maintainers of your code.

IMHO, the **correct** version of your code should be:

```
app.route("/articles")
  // GET: articles
  .get((req, res) => {
    Article.find((err, results) => {
      if (!err) {
        res.json(results);
      } else {
        res.send(err);
      };
    });
  })
```

The **correct** version of your code with `async/await` is:

```
app.route("/articles")
  // GET: articles
  .get(async (req, res) => {
      try {
          res.json(await Article.find());
      }
      catch (err) {
          res.send(err);
      }
  })
```

The **correct** version of your code with promises but without `async/await` should be:

```
app.route("/articles")
  // GET: articles
  .get((req, res) => {
      Article.find()
          .then(result => res.json(result))
          .catch(err => res.send(err));
  })
```

---

The above is of course just my **opinion** but I suggest you strongly consider it a guideline. Any of the three forms above would be perfectly acceptable to most javascript programmers and most people consider which to use a matter of taste. Personally I prefer plain promises without `await` but `async/await` is useful when you have some tricky flow control logic.

---

Note that Mongoose conveniently supports both promises and callbacks so in this specific case you can just remove the callback to use `async/await`. However not all libraries do this. If you need to convert a callback based function to a promise you need to wrap it in the Promise constructor:

```
function convertedToPromise () {
    return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
        callbackBasedFunction((err,result) => {
            if (err) {
                reject(err)
            }
            else {
                resolve(result)
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: mongoose does support promises so `Article.find()` without the callback will return a promise and will avoid the extra promisification

Comment: @Matt Oh. I don't use mongoose so I didn't know that. That would make the examples more succinct